# Need to get encrypt some sections in a web config file

Tags: asp.net, web-config, c#-2.0, configuration-files

I need to encrypt the settings section in a web config file. How can I do this?

This is my config file and it has a different name than web.config.

```
--configuration--

--settings--

--add key="conn-string" value="Dsn=XXXXXX;uid=sa;pwd=XXXXX--

--add key="provider" value="System.Data.Odbc"--

--add key="Timeout" value="300"--

--settings--


--configuration--
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this may help you:

[Encrypt sections of Web.Config or App.Config](http://dotnetprofessional.com/blog/post/2008/03/03/Encrypt-sections-of-WebConfig-or-AppConfig.aspx)

Regards